# Entity manager timeout

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, connection-timeout

I'm using Spring Data but for custom query I want to start use EntityManager.
The problem is that all query with Spring Data are working fine except query with EntityManager. I got timeout error all time for EntityManager query.

```
@Bean
public BasicDataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    ds.setUrl(MessageFormat.format(Constants.DATABASE_CONNECTION_URL, host, port, schema));
    ds.setUsername(username);
    ds.setPassword(password);
    ds.setTestWhileIdle(true);
    ds.setValidationQuery(validationQuery);
    ds.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(validationTestInterval);
    return ds;
}

@Bean
public EntityManager entityManager() {
    return entityManagerFactory(dataSource()).createEntityManager();
}

@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(BasicDataSource dataSource) {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);
    vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
    vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan(
            "com.xxx"
    );

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.provider_class", "org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", MessageFormat.format(Constants.DATABASE_CONNECTION_URL, host, port, schema));
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", username);
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password);
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment", "5");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period", "300");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", "5");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", "1000");

    factory.setJpaProperties(properties);
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();

    return factory.getObject();
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    JpaDialect jpaDialect = new HibernateJpaDialect();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    txManager.setJpaDialect(jpaDialect);
    txManager.setDefaultTimeout(60000);
    txManager.setRollbackOnCommitFailure(true);
    return txManager;
}



@Component
public class ReportGenerator {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private List<MyObject> doSomething() {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        // build query
        List<MyObject> list = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql.toString(), MyObject.class).getResultList();
        entityManager.clear();
        return list;
    }
```

Any advice?

**UPDATE 1:**

```
validationQuery = SELECT 1;
validationTestInterval = 30000
```

Answer (score 0):

**@PersistenceContext**

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

**UPDATE:**

*in my opinion: this short answer is more better than nothing and it could save me a lot of time*

[link 1](https://spring.io/blog/2006/08/07/using-jpa-in-spring-without-referencing-spring)

> That's fine, but how do I get an EnityManager?
>   This might actually be the coolest part. Basically you’d just define a DAO exactly the way you would if you weren’t using Spring by adding the @PersistenceContext JPA annotation.

[link 2 (rus)](http://javacore.ru/topic/68-jpa-spring.htm)

> 2. В бинах, где необходим менеджер сущностей пометить соответствующее поле аннотацией  @PersistenceContext

[link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101407/spring-jpa-application-managed-persistence-context-with-transactional-and-pe)

> @PersistenceContext injects a container-managed instance.

Comment: Can you provide more details? How does this answer the question? It doesn't seem very useful as-is...

Comment: @Chris, unfortunately I have no time now to make deep investigation for this issue because end of sprint, etc. But I will try to do it later. The reason why this is answer - in original post with example of entityManager usage was @ PersistenceContext annotation. So the original problem is my bad copy-paste. In any change @ Autowired -> @ PersistenceContext will fix the problem. See my update for answer but I still have no idea about behaviour in case of @ Autowired.